# TYPO3 gallery with lightbox

Tags: typo3, lightbox, image-gallery, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I have multiple images sorted in to different folders that represent albums. Now I want to display these in an image gallery on the Website, moreover the pictures should be displayed with a lightbox.

Previously the gallery extension *yet_another_gallery* (YAG) was used, sadly, this one is not supported anymore and I need a replacement for TYPO3 version 10.4.

I tried multiple gallery extensions, and *fs_media_gallery* seems to be a good fit for my needs. However, I cannot get the lightbox feature to work (I tried multiple different extensions for the lightbox *photoswipe, jn_lightbox* and *fancybox*). Does anyone have this issue before and can help me with this?

If there is another gallery extension out there that can display multiple albums and included pictures, I can try these too.

**UPDATE:**
In the end, the problem was that in the div container, which is generated by the fs_media_gallery plugin, was missing one parameter. After adding the parameter to the div container, it worked. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: The fs_media_gallery documentation says that the lightbox feature should be used together with Bootstrap Code. Maybe the fs_media_gallery developer means  the Bootstrap Modal dialog? I don't know. Until your post I was  not even aware that fs_media_gallery existed.

Comment: I use 'bm_image_gallery' with my own lightbox library for showing images and videos in a lightbox (magnific popup). So I don't need an additional extension for the lightbox.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  @Robert I installed ‘bm_image_gallery’ and tried to set the LightBox up, (I have a JavaScript- and CSS-file). However in the Documentation is only a 'cssClass' option, how do I use the JavaScript File with this extension.

Comment: @knb I understand it as example, because of this sentence "For a LightBox example use this extension in combi with EXT:bootstrap_package".

Comment: There should be no problems using Fancybox, it is very simple, see https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/api